# first symbol not printing but the rest is normally printing

Tags: python, dictionary, morse-code

I am not sure why the first asterisk is not printing, does anyone have any ideas? BTW I am using a dictionary.

input

```
error
```

output

```
' ****'
```

expected output

```
    '*****'
```

```py
    MORSE_CODES={'A':'.-','B':'-...','C':'-.-.',
    'D':'-..','E':'.','F':'..-.','G':'--.',
    'H':'....','I':'..','J':'.---','K':'-.-',
    'L':'.-..','M':'--','N':'-.','O':'---',
    'P':'.--.','Q':'--.-','R':'.-.',
    'S':'...','T':'-','U':'..-','V':'...-',
    'W':'.--','X':'-..-','Y':'-.--','Z':'--..'}

    def encode_Morse(my_msg):
   
    
      my_msg_Morse=" "
      for letter in my_msg:
        
        if letter!=" " and letter not in MORSE_CODES:
          my_msg_Morse+="*"
        elif letter!=" ":
           my_msg_Morse+= MORSE_CODES[letter]+"  "
        else:
          my_msg_Morse+="   "
      my_msg_Morse = my_msg_Morse[:-1]
      return my_msg_Morse
```

Comment: What is MORSE_CODES?

Comment: the dictionary.

Comment: How it looks like?

Comment: check the edit .

Comment: Why do you skip the last character by doing this `my_msg_Morse = my_msg_Morse[:-1]`?

Comment: because it adds two spaces at the end when encoding to morse

Comment: teh add only required things. since you skip the last characters, one asterisk is getting removed from output.

Comment: Allow me to expand on @lllrnr101's correct response.  You're subtracting a space because you are adding too many when you have a letter, but when you have a star, you don't add any spaces.  Thus, you are deleting a valuable character, not a space.  You might consider creating a list instead of a string, and use `' '.join(lst)`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not returning the full string and that the *last* asterisk is not printing. You can fix this problem by amending the assignment `my_msg_Morse = my_msg_Morse[:-1]`
to
 `my_msg_Morse = my_msg_Morse`.

If you weren't adding blank spaces with this condition (for the characters matched by your dictionary - i.e. the capital letters)

```
elif letter!=" ": 
     my_msg_Morse+= MORSE_CODES[letter]+"  "
```

it would be more clear that you have this problem generally. Consider the test case where you don't add blanks:

Input:
`ERROR`

Expected Output:
 `..-..-.---.-.`

Actual Output: 
 `..-..-.---.-`

However, you are adding blank spaces after each rendering of a capital into morse code. So this loss of the final character (a blank space) is mostly unobserved.

I don't know what your requirements are but if they are satisfied by returning a string with no trailing white space you could return `my_msg_Morse.rstrip()`. The `rstrip()` method of the string object removes all trailing white space. This way, you could preserve your within-string white space while eliminating trailing white space. I also like Tim Robert's suggestion (in a comment to your original question) of using a list and joining it.